# Create another instance of GNOME shell extension for development purposes

Tags: gnome-shell, extension, gnome-shell-extension

I have the [Clipboard Indicator](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/779/clipboard-indicator/) GNOME shell extension installed. How can I create another instance of the extension (for development purposes)?

I created a [fork](https://github.com/rahidelvi/gnome-shell-extension-clipboard-indicator) of the [original project](https://github.com/Tudmotu/gnome-shell-extension-clipboard-indicator) and cloned the files to

`/home/rahi/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions`.

I renamed my working directory to `clipboard-indicator@rahi.ca`, as the original extension is named `clipboard-indicator@tudmotu.com`.

I restarted the GNOME shell using <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F2</kbd> and then `r`. When I try to enable my cloned extension using the Tweak tool, I do not see a second Clipboard Indicator toggle.

I'm running Ubuntu 16.04 with GNOME shell 3.18.5.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Open the `metadata.json` file located at
`/home/rahi/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions/clipboard-indicator@rahi.ca/`
 and put `"clipboard-indicator@rahi.ca"` for the `"uuid"` entry so that it looks like

```
"uuid": "clipboard-indicator@rahi.ca",
```

(i.e. it should match the directory containing the `metadata.json` file).
You may also want to change the value for the `"name"` parameter.

Then save the file and restart GNOME shell (or re-login).

Then you should find another instance of the extension in *Tweaks* > *Extensions* (I renamed it "*Clipboard Indicator for development*"):

[image]

<sub>To learn more about *uuid* see [this](https://wiki.gnome.org/Projects/GnomeShell/Extensions#Anatomy_of_an_extension).</sub>

Comment: I gave this a try and unfortunately it did not work.

Comment: @rahi Works pretty well for me: https://i.stack.imgur.com/NaEIO.png. Should not be necessary, but try changing the `"name:"` too in `metadata.json`.

Comment: @pmsky YES! changing the name did it!

Comment: sorry off topic. Can you point us to the theme you're using?

Comment: @rahi [Vimix](https://github.com/vinceliuice/vimix-gtk-themes/) (beryl variant).